QuantLib OISRateHelper Accrual and Fixing different calendars
My question is specific to SOFR OIS swaps, but can be extended to other cases, where relevant: SOFR fixings (SOFRRATE Index) operate on GT (US govt bond mkt) calendar, while SOFR OIS swaps operate on FD (US Fed Reserve calendar).  When using OISRateHelper, to get the object to have the correct start and end dates, I have to feed a custom-made index that is based on the FD calendar, rather than the correct GT calendar.  This also has a downstream effect of the rate being slightly off as the expected logic when a fixing doesn't exist, is to compound over the relevant period using the last available fixing.  Is there a way to specify to OISRateHelper a fixing calendar that is different from the accrual calendar?  Is there a workaround available that reflects the expected behavior correctly?
import QuantLib as ql

calculation_date = ql.Date(17, 4, 2025)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

cal_FD = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.FederalReserve)
cal_GT = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)

yts_FD = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
yts_GT = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()

idx_FD = ql.OvernightIndex("USD ON Test", 0, ql.USDCurrency(), cal_FD, ql.Actual360(), yts_FD)
idx_GT = ql.OvernightIndex("USD ON Test", 0, ql.USDCurrency(), cal_GT, ql.Actual360(), yts_GT)

swaps = {ql.Period("1W"): 1/100,}
tenors = list(swaps.keys())
quotes = [ql.SimpleQuote(swaps[k]) for k in tenors]
handles = [ql.QuoteHandle(quote) for quote in quotes]

def create_rate_helpers(idx):
    rate_helpers = []
    for quote, tenor in zip(handles, tenors):
        helper = ql.OISRateHelper(2, tenor, quote, idx, endOfMonth=False, 
                                fixedCalendar=cal_FD, paymentCalendar=cal_FD)
        rate_helpers.append(helper)
    
    return rate_helpers

rate_helpers_FD = create_rate_helpers(idx_FD)
rate_helpers_GT = create_rate_helpers(idx_GT)

print(rate_helpers_FD[0].earliestDate())
print(rate_helpers_GT[0].earliestDate())

print(rate_helpers_FD[0].maturityDate())
print(rate_helpers_GT[0].maturityDate())


Hi, I don't think there's a workaround.  May you open an issue at https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues so we can look into implementing it?
